# Samba fileserver prevent archive extraction

Tags: ubuntu, unzip, samba

I have a Samba fileserver with Ubuntu 14.4 LTS 64 bit working on a lan with many Windows 7 client. Is there any way to prevent users, that can access to shared or private folders from their Windows pc, to extract archives there?
I know that would still be possible to extract archives on the pc and then to transfer unzipped folders. This block would be enough to discourage the extraction anyway.
If this is not possible, can I log who extracted an archive? The problem is that extracted files do not belong to the user who ran the unzip command from his windows pc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No. Samba has no way of knowing what the source of the file is. Everything is a file, everything looks the same. Samba can't tell that this file being created was extracted from a *.zip file.

I can't imagine why you would want to block extracting archives. Maybe some thing else would be more appropriate for your needs, e.g. quotas?

Comment: Thank you, I though it was like that...
I want to block extracting archives to discourage inappropriate behavior of my colleagues: we have consistent zipped archives on the server, but they unzip theme there, maybe make some changes and later they use the unzipped (unconsistent) folders.